# Update attribute on a has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am printing a list of user's contacts and want to give the user the ability to mark each contact as "done". (Essentially marking them off their to do list).

How do I update the :done attribute for the specific contact?

This is form with a hidden field is not working:

```
<% if current_user.contacts.any? %>
<% current_user.contacts.each do |c| %> 
    <li id="<%= c.id %>">
        <%= c.name %><br/>

        <%= form_for(@contact) do |f| %>
            <%= f.hidden_field :done, :value=>true %>
            <%= f.submit "Mark as done", class: "btn btn-small btn-link"%>
        <% end %>

    </li>
<% end %>
```

I get this error:

```
Template is missing Missing template contacts/create, application/create with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in: * "C:/Sites/rails_projects/sample_app/app/views"
```

This is my contacts controller:

```
def create
  @contact = current_user.contacts.build(params[:contact])
  if @contact.save
    flash[:success] = "Contact saved!"
    redirect_to root_url
  else
    flash[:error] = "Something is wrong"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, perhaps due to validation rules, the `@contact` object can't be saved.
In this case, the `else` branch in your create action doesn't specify what to render, so it's looking for a `create` template.  You may be able to simply add a line to `render :action => :new` or `redirect_to :action => :new`, assuming your new action doesn't require preloading additional data.

```
else
  flash[:error] = "Something is wrong"
  redirect_to :action => :new
end
```

You can also use `respond_with` instead of explicitly redirecting, which will render the `new` action if errors were found:

```
def create
  @contact = current_user.contacts.build(params[:contact])
  if @contact.save
    flash[:success] = "Contact saved!"
  else
    flash[:error] = "Something is wrong"
  end
  respond_with @contact, :location => root_url
end
```

Comment: Is @contact = current_user.contacts.build(params[:contact]) the right method to call here if I just want to update ':done', not create a new contact?

Comment: You can use that to 'build' a new contact, but that won't update anything in the database.  You'll just have an unpersisted contact in memory.

Comment: So what should I put in the form_for(____) then? And what should that method be?

Comment: If you are trying to update a contact that exists in the database, you should be using the `edit` action and set `@contact = current_user.contacts.find(params[:id])`.  The submit button will forward the form data to the `update` action (not the `create` action) and you will again need to load up the contact (same code as before) and update the attributes using params[:contact] instead of building a new object.

Comment: Looking at your original view again, you don't need an `edit` action really.  You can call `form_for(c)` since you are using `c` to hold a user's contact in that block.  The rest still applies (using `update` instead of `create`, load object by id, update attributes from params...)

Comment: You're right. I dropped the edit action and just used the create again. I think Ruby knows that the contact exists already and just updates the "Done" field to true when the button is clicked. Thanks for your help